# Add, save and delete tablerow

Tags: android, save, row, android-tablelayout, tablerow

I want to create a `table` with a `button` that every time it is clicked adds a `tablerow` with three `TextView`. For the moment I could only add to the `tablerow` without `TextView`, however, has the problem that when I close the application the lines created are not saved, who can help me?

This is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button btnAddItem = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addItemTableRow);
        btnAddItem.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                TableLayout table = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tableLayout1);

                TableRow row = new TableRow(MainActivity.this);

                TextView t = new TextView(MainActivity.this);

                t.setText("Add table row");

                row.addView(t);

                table.addView(row, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: i add the tablerow but when i close the application the tablerow are not saved.

Comment: if you want to save the data. you just try SqLite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't add permanently views to a Layout ("permanently" means that survive to the application being closed).

If you are referring to the application being **put in background** (i.e. when the user presses the home button), or when the user turns the device, or when you start another activity and you go back to this one android gives you the possibility to "save" the state of your activity with two callbacks:
namely **onSaveInstanceState** and **onRestoreInstanceState**

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    savedInstanceState.putInt("numRows", rowsNum);
    for (int i=1;i<rowsNum+1;i++) {
         savedInstanceState.putString("row"+i+"1", "Text of the first row first cell");
         savedInstanceState.putString("row"+i+"2", "Text of the first row second cell");
         savedInstanceState.putString("row"+i+"3", "Text of the first row third cell");
    }
}

@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    int numRows = savedInstanceState.getInt("numRows");
    for (int i=1;i<rowsNum+1;i++) {
         String cell1 = savedInstanceState.getString("row"+i+"1");
         String cell2 = savedInstanceState.getString("row"+i+"2");
         String cell3 = savedInstanceState.getString("row"+i+"3");
         //re-create the table here from the strings
    }
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: thanks for the help...I wanted to do by creating XML files but do not know how to do